# What items can I deduct in my 1040 to increase my child tax credit refund?

Tags: united-states, taxes, income-tax, tax-deduction, tax-credit

The past few years I reported wages, capital gains, rent (about 20k/yr) and since we have 7 children, we haven't paid taxes and got a few thousand dollars child tax refund. The rent brings the total amount we receive down from what we could have been getting. This year I switched jobs and my reported wages are expected be higher and might adversely affect the refund. What things can I  report to increase my chances of retaining the child tax credits and perhaps a refund? For instance, I tried putting in to my tax software to amortize the rental that we have, but it didn't affect the amount of child tax credit refund at all. Can anyone suggest things that are not obvious to tax a amateur that can be reported that would positively affect the refund amount?

Comment: Are you saying that your 2021 income was too high to qualify for the full Child Tax Credit? Are you complaining that you wish the refund check you will be getting was bigger? You normally cannot deduct your rent; where are you deducting that?

Comment: Which country are you in?

Comment: I am a U.S.A. expat, does it matter where I am?

Comment: When it comes to taxes, yes, it does. Taxes are different in every country on the planet.

Comment: I am filing an IRS 1040 and that is what I am basing my questions off of

Comment: I am trying to legally get as big as I can refund, it helps a lot. Expenses just go up so I don't want an increase in salary here to cause less income from a possible refund. Then it becomes a wash. As it is we're not talking millions here but it helps.

Comment: I understand. Let me ask again: Are you at an income level where you are not qualifying for the full child tax credit? (Above $75k if single or married-filing-separately, above $112.5k if head-of-household, above $150k if married-filing-jointly)

Comment: @BenMiller-RememberMonica I take it the OP has a *rental property* that provides them income, not that they pay rent.

Comment: We are under the 150K and we are qualifying for it. However, based on my OLT software, it doesn't show the full amount that it could have been and the point of this thread is to ask experts like you if are there any legal deductions that exist and I can use to gain whatever the software deducted. Until now, it wasn't relevant. Right now, the rental income seems to have caused OLT software to lower the refund amount. I just plug in my numbers, the software does the calculations.

Comment: We also pay rent. We wanted to live elsewhere so we rented out our primary residence and rent elsewhere and the amount is basically a wash but I report the income as I am supposed to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am going to focus just on the rental property, and answer from a US perspective.

This is from the question:

> The rent brings the total amount we receive down from what we could
> have been getting.

and this is from a comment:

> We also pay rent. We wanted to live elsewhere so we rented out our
> primary residence and rent elsewhere and the amount is basically a
> wash but I report the income as I am supposed to.

Make sure you are reducing the income impact of the rent received by taking the deductions for the property tax, mortgage interest, HOA fees, repairs and the like. If you have a management company handling the details the cost of that service can also reduce the rental income.

The biggest thing that needs to be claimed is the depreciation of the house, but not the land.

The good thing is that all these expenses blunt the impact of the rental income. You can do these things even if you don't itemize, and you use the standard deduction.

I do not know how this impacts your taxes if the property isn't in the United States.

Comment: ty, this was helpful. Now part of my questions is, what other such suggestions should I be looking into to positively affect the refund? Feel free to throw things out. I want to make sure that I didn't miss anything and the software as well.